# __lt__ and print operator overload

Tags: python

I have this assignment in which I have to define a class named `Person` with attributes `name`, `surname` and `age`. I have done getter and setter methods; now I have an issue with overloading operators.
First, I need to overload a print operator (which I have done); second, I need to overload "less than" operator which gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Person' and 'Person'
```

And in the last step, I need to compare the ages of different persons e.g.:

```
Sabine=Person("Sabine","Musterfrau",17)
Anton_Junior=Person("Anton","Mueller",14)
print(Sabine < Anton_Junior) should return false and vice versa
```

My problem is: 1. the type error and 2. I have already overloaded print method and they want me to use the default `print()` later.

Here is my code:

```
from sys import stdout
class Person:
    def __init__(self,vorname,nachname,alter):
        self.vorname=vorname
        self.nachname=nachname
        self._alter=alter
    def get_Alter(self):
            return self._alter
    def set_Alter(self,alter2):
        self._alter=alter2
    def print(person):
        stdout.write("Name:"+person.vorname+" Nachname:"+person.nachname+" Alter:"+str(person._alter)+"\n")
    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self._alter() < other._alter()

Sabine=Person("Sabine","Musterfrau",17)
Sabine.set_Alter(18)
Anton_Junior=Person("Anton","Mueller",14)
Anton_Senior=Person("Anton","Mueller",80)
print(Sabine < Anton_Junior)
print(Sabine)
```

Ok, just finished my task, thank you all!!!

Comment: This code does not give the error you claim. It does give a TypeError, but with the message " 'int' object is not callable", because for some reason you are calling the `_alter` objects within your `__lt__` method.

Comment: Python is not Java. We don't use getters & setters for simple attribute access. And if you really need getters & setters in Python _please_ use the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) so that callers can still access your getter & setter methods using simple attribute syntax.

Comment: fixed it now with your help, thank you

Comment: But I get unexpected result after print(Sabine)-----><__main__.Person object at 0x18136fdf98>

Comment: Give your class a [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `self._alter` is a field/property/value (name it whatever you want) and not method. This should help you:

```
def __lt__(self,other):
        return self._alter < other._alter
```

When it comes to second problem::

> I have already overloaded print method and they want me to use the default print() later.

Refefine `__str__()` method.

```
>>> class MyClass:
...   def __str__(self):
...     return 'This is my class'
... 
>>> mc = MyClass()
>>> print(mc)
This is my class
```